# How to make Ruby var= return value assigned, not value passed in?

Tags: ruby

There's a nice idiom for adding to lists stored in a hash table:

```
(hash[key] ||= []) << new_value
```

Now, suppose I write a derivative hash class, like the ones found in Hashie, which does a deep-convert of any hash I store in it. Then what I store will not be the same object I passed to the = operator; Hash may be converted to Mash or Clash, and arrays may be copied.

Here's the problem. Ruby apparently returns, from the var= method, the value passed in, not the value that's stored. It doesn't matter what the var= method returns. The code below demonstrates this:

```
class C
  attr_reader :foo
  def foo=(value)
    @foo = (value.is_a? Array) ? (value.clone) : value
  end
end

c=C.new
puts "assignment: #{(c.foo ||= []) << 5}"
puts "c.foo is #{c.foo}"
puts "assignment: #{(c.foo ||= []) << 6}"
puts "c.foo is #{c.foo}"
```

output is

```
assignment: [5]
c.foo is []
assignment: [6]
c.foo is [6]
```

When I posted this as a bug to Hashie, Danielle Sucher explained what was happening and pointed out that "foo.send :bar=, 1" returns the value returned by the bar= method. (Hat tip for the research!) So I guess I could do:

```
c=C.new
puts "clunky assignment: #{(c.foo || c.send(:foo=, [])) << 5}"
puts "c.foo is #{c.foo}"
puts "assignment: #{(c.foo || c.send(:foo=, [])) << 6}"
puts "c.foo is #{c.foo}"
```

which prints

```
clunky assignment: [5]
c.foo is [5]
assignment: [5, 6]
c.foo is [5, 6]
```

Is there any more elegant way to do this?

Comment: I don't think you can override the return value of an assignment.

Comment: I think using a `default_proc` is a much nicer idiom than that mess of syntax at the top of your question. I also think that your `foo=` method is an abuse of the expected behavior of assignment in Ruby, the caller should do the cloning.

Comment: Mu, how would you write a Hashie::Mash, without modifying what is stored? I agree that normally assignment should store what's given. But with a hash, you're more adding to a data structure than assigning a value to a variable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
c.foo ||= []  
c.foo << 5
```

Using two lines of code isn't the end of the world, and it's easier on the eyes.

Comment: Yeah, and I could combine them with a semicolon: "c.foo||=[];c.foo<<5" which is almost as concise, and more readable, than "(c.foo||=[])<<5". The only problem is that foo has to be evaluated twice - which only matters if I'm doing c[foo-expression] rather than c.foo, and then I could do "foo=foo-expression;c[foo]||=[];c[foo]=5". Certainly better than the c.send hack I proposed. Thanks!

Answer (score 6):

Assignments evaluate to the value that is being assigned. Period.

In some other languages, assignments are statements, so they don't evaluate to anything. Those are really the only two sensible choices. Either don't evaluate to anything, or evaluate to the value being assigned. Everything else would be too surprising.

Since Ruby doesn't have statements, there is really only one choice.

The only "workaround" for this is: don't use assignment.

Comment: "Since Ruby doesn't have statements, there is really only one choice."  Not true, in C++ the author of the assignment operators decides what is going to be returned.  Typically the lhs (not the rhs) is returned.  Of course you are going to say "Everything else would be too surprising", but in the case of C++ returning the lhs is not surprising at all.

Comment: In Ruby, the LHS is a variable or a method. Neither variables nor methods are objects in Ruby, and only objects can be returned, therefore, this choice doesn't exist in Ruby.

Answer (score 1):

The prettiest way to do this is to use default value for hash:

```
# h = Hash.new { [] }
h = Hash.new { |h,k| h[k] = [] }
```

But be ware that you cant use `Hash.new([])` and then `<<` because of way how Ruby store variables:

```
h = Hash.new([])
h[:a] # => []
h[:b] # => []
h[:a] << 10
h[:b] # => [10] O.o
```

it's caused by that Ruby store variables by reference, so as we created only one array instance, ad set it as default value then it will be shared between all hash cells (unless it will be overwrite, i.e. by `h[:a] += [10]`).

It is solved by using constructor with block ([doc](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Hash.html)) `Hash.new { [] }`. With this each time when new key is created block is called and each value is different array.

*EDIT*: Fixed error that @Uri Agassi is writing about.

Comment: You solution does not work: `h = Hash.new { [] }; h[:a] << 10; h[:a] # => []`. That is because default value of a hash is not actually _assigned_ to the missing key, it is only _returned_...